# JSONPath - Get full JSON (as is) using expression

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

Can I get the **full JSON string** using [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)?

I failed using different combinations `$` `*` `$..*` `$*`

> $ The root element to query. This starts all path expressions.
>
> * Wildcard. Available anywhere a name or numeric are required.

I'm using JMeter's [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and sometimes I need to retrieve all/full response using JSONPath expression

**EDIT**

Same results with `$[*]` as @Daniel suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution using expressions: `$` and changing Apply to:

```
Main Sample and sub-samples
```

save the full JSON to variable

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$[*]
```

Although `$.*` (and `$..*`) should work too. All work with [Jayway and Goessner](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

Daniel

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, probably JMeter wrap it differently